# Sense of command collate in create table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand function of command `collate` (a little). It is truth that I did not test if it is possible to have tables with various collation (or even various charset) inside one DB.

But I found that (at least in phpmyadmin) when I create any DB, I set its charset and collation - and if I miss this command in `CREATE TABLE ...`, then automatically will be set collation set in creation of DB.

So, my question is: What is sense of presence of command `collate` in sql of `CREATE TABLE ...` if it can be missing there - and is recommended to have collate in `CREATE TABLE ...` or is it irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server if you don't specify the `COLLATE` it is defaulted to what ever DB is set to. Thus there is no danger in not specifying.

In MySQL behavior is the same:

> The table character set and collation are used as default values for
>   column definitions if the column character set and collation are not
>   specified in individual column definitions. [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html)

Collate is only used when you want to specify to non-default value. If all you are using is English character set than you have nothing to worry about it. If you store data from multiple languages than you have specify specific collation to ensure what characters are stored correctly.

Comment: Should not be a *behavior* instead dehavior?